# What are the important things to study in infinity categories?

Tags: online-resources, higher-category-theory, motivation

I am reading about infinity categories.

My source is http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/cisinski/CatLR.pdf

My aim is to think categorically so that all the constructions I deal with are natural (till now homotopy colimit\limit, the perspective on derived functors is very nice. Also I liked the construction of model category letting you tell when two maps are homotopic. Also simplicial sets are a good way to capture degeneracies). I am trying to study Spectra as a concrete example.

Also I would like to be able to read later about derived algebraic geometry.

However, a lot of the book is very dull to me; proving what the fibrations\cofibrations are in the model structure on simplicial sheaves. I am okay with just being told the answer; it's frustrating to go through 100's of pages proving it.

My questions are:

1. What are the fun important parts (by the aims I described) that I should read about?
2. Am I doing harm to myself by accepting technical facts like who the fibrations\cofibrations are?

Rumors I've heard from smart friends are - compact objects, some adjoint theorems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am obviously no expert, but to close this question; I found that instead of sludging through books, the first lectures of the following were very helpful to me-

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCk1WaD2LYVvNiRPteCBeSsA

(Seeing that a limit in infinity categories is the standard homotopy limit, and working out why showed me how infinity categories keep track of the homotopy as well).